# Creating Column Rules in Columnizer jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some text and columnizer sorts it into 3 columns.

```
<div id="press">
  <div class="wide">
  Placeholder=
</div>
```

the columnizer script is like this

```
$(function(){
  $('.dp-highlighter').addClass("dontsplit");
  $('li').addClass("dontsplit");
  $('.wide').columnize({width:250});
  $('.thin').columnize({width:200});
});
```

AND my CSS is like this;

```
.column p, .column h1{ padding: 15px; }
#press {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px 100px; 
  width: 80%;
  color: white;
  font-family: courier, Times New, serif;
}
.wide, .thin { clear:both; }
```

How can i get a line to display between columns that is similar to the column-rule function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an additional `<div>` *directly* inside the block that should be columnized:

```
<div class="wide">
    <div>
        Here goes your text
    </div>
<div>
```

and add the rule as a CSS border to this `<div>`:

```
.column div {
     border-left: 1px solid black;
 }
```

Directly adding the border to the `.column` does not work, but prevents the text to be columnized in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a border on either the left or right side:

```
.column{
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```